# Web service cache with excemption

Tags: asp.net, web-services, caching, asmx, vb.net-2010

I need to cache the result of the web service that 
I am creating but it also i want to know how many times it was accessed.

example,

```
<WebMethod(CacheDuration:=60)> 
Public Function DisplayData(ByVal Code As Integer) As System.Xml.XmlDocument
        ((some code here))
        Return Xml
End Function
```

Input:

```
/Service.asmx/DisplayData?Code=55
/Service.asmx/DisplayData?Code=55
/Service.asmx/DisplayData?Code=55
```

Output:

```
A cached result of
<DisplayData>
    <Code>55</Code>
</DisplayData>
```

and

```
DisplayDataCounter = 3
```

If the web service was **accessed 3 times** with `/Service.asmx/DisplayData?Code=55`.
It will just **cache the result**.

But i want also a **counter** that will count how many times it was **accessed**.
Is it possible? How can I possibly do it?

Comment: If that is your only method that is cached you could investigate if the [ASP.NET performance counter Cache hit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxk122b4.aspx) is a solution. Otherwise you have to bring the caching inside your method.

Comment: how will I bring the caching inside method? Can you please give me some link on how to do it?

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching(v=vs.100).aspx). Your method needs to run for every call, there you can increment your hitcounter and check if the data is available in the cache. Do notice that this has effect on your (network) performance characteristics so measure your performance and load if that is crtical

Comment: Thank you for the info @JohnSaunders. Also thanks for the link rene.